# Redshift LIKE from a list of values

Tags: amazon-redshift

I would like to filter from my table **orders** all zipcodes that start with the letters "B1", "NW1", "C13", etc. For example, postcodes in the UK can be "NW8 8AB".

I am using this query in Redshift but it is very inefficient now that I have a list of 500 codes.

```
select * from orders
where zipcode like 'B1%' or zipcode like 'NW1%' or zipcode like 'C13%'
```

Is there a way of doing it in a more efficient way?

I was thinking something like:

```
select * from orders
where zipcode like ('B1', 'NW1', 'C13') + %
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, which looks at all the content before the first space, which for this case it works given that I only have the first part of the postcodes before the space.

```
select * from orders
where split_part(zipcode, ' ', 1) like ('B1', 'NW1', 'C13')
```